# Como verificar se minha aplicação spring está em ambiente de produção?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

quando estiver em produção quero que quando caia numa exceção mande um email para o suporte mas somente em produção , em desenvolvimento não quero que ele execute esta tarefa .

Comment: Você pode criar uma propriedade em um arquivo de configuração e fazer o código olhar esta propriedade para saber em que ambiente está rodando.

Comment: achei a resolução do problema o propio spring-boot tem uma classe nativa chamada Environment so injetar ela :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solução foi injetar uma classe do spring boot chamada Environment .

```
@Autowired
private Environment environment;

environment.getActiveProfiles()[0].equals("production"));
```

Arquivo application.properties

```
#ENVIRONMENT
spring.profiles.active=develop
```